# output not printing after entering 0

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to print a message after the user inputs a 0 but nothing is outputted, the same goes for entering 200, and that seems to work fine except the 0.

i have tried putting and/or and nothing.

im just learning python from last week, so i am a beginner

thanks in advance

```
highway_num = int(input())

if 0 < highway_num < 100:
    print(f'I-{highway_num} is primary,', end='')
    if highway_num % 2 == 0:
        print(' going east/west.')
    else:
        print(' going north/south.')
if 99 < highway_num < 1000:
    if highway_num == 0 or highway_num == 200:
        print(f'{highway_num} is not a valid interstate highway number.')
    else:
        print(f'I-{highway_num} is auxiliary,', end='')
```

Comment: Check your < signs (<=)

Comment: This is because of this `if 99 < highway_num < 1000:` your program stops here and does not execute the following if. This says if `highway_num` is greater than `99` and less than `1000`

Comment: As `200` is already within 99 ~ 1000. Then the second if is reached and executed...

Comment: Thank you for all the comments! They were all very useful in identifying my coding mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helo steph! I added some comments in you code bellow. Please, check if it's good enough for you.

```
highway_num = int(input())

# Numbers from 1 to 99
if 0 < highway_num < 100:
    print(f'I-{highway_num} is primary,', end='')
    if highway_num % 2 == 0:
        print(' going east/west.')
    else:
        print(' going north/south.')
# Numbers from 100 to 999
# I changed your IF for an ELIF statement.
elif 99 < highway_num < 1000:
    # Value 0 is impossible here! :) since this block is only executed if the number is between 100 and 999.
    if highway_num == 0 or highway_num == 200:
        print(f'{highway_num} is not a valid interstate highway number.')
    else:
        print(f'I-{highway_num} is auxiliary,', end=' ')
        print('sorry.') # Added so the console message is printed.
# This ELSE is any not valid number.
else:
    print(f'{highway_num} is not valid. Try a number from 1 to 999')
```

Comment: The comments are very helpful and make me understand the lines better and what they do! Thank you for the help :)